# Where is the overview activity source code in aosp?

Tags: android-source

Can anyone point me to the aosp source for the overview / preview activity in 5.0? It performs several functions that I need in a current project (capture screens for several recent activities and display them as opengl textures). The need is to get screen captures for activities / programs other than my own. I'm trying to create somthing similiar to the overview display, but with different visual display.